# junit error: initiallization error: coused an error: no rannable method

Tags: java, junit

I am having this error while all my methods in this test are successful - all of them return true. Also tried to make boolean for each method call and use only one call for assertTrue(a && b && c && d && e).

I run the junit test in java - netbeans.

My junit code (first time using junit) is:

```
package redis_fast_algo;

import data_sets.FastSortAlgoData;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FastSortAlgoStudyTest {

    private DataMaker dataMake;
    private final static boolean BEFORE_DELETE = false;

    public FastSortAlgoStudyTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        dataMake = new DataMaker();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of study method, of class FastSortAlgoStudy.
     */
    @Test
    public void testStudy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("study");
        FastSortAlgoData data = dataMake.getData(5);
        FastSortAlgoStudy instance = new FastSortAlgoStudy(data);
        FastSortAlgoTest testStudy = new FastSortAlgoTest(data);
        testStudy.prepareForTest();
        instance.study();

        assertTrue(testStudy.testCheckFolderStudyCounter(BEFORE_DELETE));
        assertTrue(testStudy.testCheckBodyPart(BEFORE_DELETE));
        assertTrue(testStudy.testCheckTitlePart(BEFORE_DELETE));
        assertTrue(testStudy.testCheckFoldersHistoryWithData(BEFORE_DELETE));
        assertTrue(testStudy.testRemoveFolderHistory());
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem again?  If you say your tests pass then why do you see an error stating there's no runnable method?

Comment: Which JUnit test runner are you using.

Comment: The tests pass (my 5 methods return true, and they are working good) on Debug test mode only. Using Junit 4.12v. But if I do "test project" it fails with the massege that I wrote above: initiallization error: coused an error: no rannable method. I think its problem with cunfiguration and not with the code - just made another "debug test file" without breaking points and had success massege.